# How to access to Task argument?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

Suppose I have a `List<Task>`:

```
private readonly List<Task> _tasks = new List<Task>(new Task[9]);
```

I want create a `Task` for start the `DoWorkAsync` method available inside the class `Foo`, so what I did is the following:

```
_tasks[0] = new Task<Foo>(() => new Foo().DoWorkAsync());
```

so the `Foo` class contains `DoWorkAsync` method which have a design similar to this:

```
public async Task HeavyAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        string newData = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        Console.WriteLine(newData);
        await Task.Delay(200);
    }
}
```

actually I can start the `Task` using `_tasks[0].Start();`.

This works, but the main problem is that I want access to the public property of `Foo` class and I can't, because when I type this: `_tasks[0].`

I'll get the following method:

[image]

I also tried using `GetAwaiter()` and `await`:

```
var foo = await _tasks[0];
```

but I'll get the following error:

> Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable

How can I access to the `Foo` properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the interface of your method. A task is just a "function pointer" that is executed and then finished. If you need the object, that contains the executed function, then you have to save or return it somewhere.

I would do the following: change the async method to return an object like:

```
public async Task<Foo> HeavyAsync()
{
  while (true)
  {
    string newData = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    Console.WriteLine(newData);
    await Task.Delay(200);
  }
  return this;
}
```

then this statement

```
var foo = await _tasks[0];
```

should give you with foo a reference to your Foo-object.

UPDATE:

Or you give your class Foo the following property and methods:

```
class Foo
{
    private Task runningTask {get;set;}

    public void StartTask()
    {
       runningTask = Task.Start( () => ....);
    }

    public async Task WaitTask()
    {
       await runningTask;
    }

    public bool IsRunning => runningTask != null && runningTask.Status......
```

And instead of holding a list of Task in your calling method, you might hold the list of Foo instances.

Comment: But what if I have a property called `IsRunning` inside the class `Foo` and I need to access to that property using the `Task`?

Comment: Ah, I see. Then you need to save the Task as property within your Foo-class and instead of having a list of Task<Foo> in your calling method you then have to hold a list of Foo. I will update the answer

Comment: @gofal3 thanks, I like your update. I have a question: if I create a `List<Foo>` and the `DoWorkAsync` method is a `Task`, then each instance of `Foo` will execute a different `Task`?

Comment: Yes. You create a List<Foo> and for every instance you call StartTask, then every instance will call internally a Task.Start, so you will have a separate Task for every Foo instance.